# Minimum length required for the runway landing and takeoff of ATR 72-600?

Tags: commercial-aviation, atr-72

What is the minimun length required for the runway landing and takeoff of ATR 72-600?
obs: altitude of 1000ft at 30 degrees

Comment: ATR 42 runway requirements
Close to 500 airports worldwide have a runway whose length extends between 800 meters and 1,000 meters and could accept the ATR 42-600S. The standard ATR42-600 requires a runway length of 1,050 meters
Source:Google

Comment: ATR42-600 and ATR72-600 require a different runway length

Answer (score 1):

Take-off: 1315m; Landing: 915m

from: https://www.atr-aircraft.com/our-aircraft/atr-72-600/

Comment: That standard value is probably for sea level @ 15°C, not for 1000ft @ 30°C as the question asks.

Comment: You’re right. Think my answer is not correct. I guess there’s a table for numbers somewhere.